# Tutorial on how to build a small isapi server from scratch ? (not an isapi filter or extension)

Tags: c#, php, c, iis, isapi

I want the smallest server possible not a full blown opensource isapi server, it's for learning purpose not for real use. Can't find any on google.

Comment: That's because no one bothers writing them.

Comment: So no one bothers how it works ? There's no real software engineers any more ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to do some PHP development on Windows? Is this the reason for wanting a lightweight server?

I would suggest looking at [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (a bit old now) or [Z:WAMP](http://zwamp.sourceforge.net/) that has a full PHP and Apache distribution that can run anywhere (and not a heavy install - its portable!).

Comment: No I don't want to do development I want to learn to create a server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how small this is, but how about the best of both worlds, full isapi server and designed for developers: [IIS Express 7.5](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/).  Currently Beta, but works great for developing and testing.

Comment: I'm not looking for a server I'm looking for SOURCE CODE as tiny as possible to study it :)